# How do I subscribe to an RSS feed in Mavericks?

Tags: macos, rss

I would like to subscribe to some RSS feeds. I originally had them in Mail, which worked just fine. But after upgrading to Mavericks, the RSS feeds disappeared, and I get this message when I click on an RSS feed link:

[image]

How do I subscribe to an RSS feed, if this won't work?

Comment: RSS support was removed from Mail and Safari back in Lion (10.7), I think. You'll have to use a third-party app like [NetNewsWire](http://netnewswireapp.com).

Comment: @daGUY I was using Lion before Mavericks, and it worked.

Comment: You're right, it was [Mountain Lion that removed RSS from Mail](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/07/os-x-10-8/9/#mail), not Lion.

Answer (score 1):

An option you might look into is [Feedly](http://feedly.com). They have a Safari plugin (and probably other browsers) and work well enough.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, Apple dropped support for RSS in Mountain Lion (OS X 10.8). You'll need a third-party RSS reader. Once you get one, you can get a *subscribe* button in Safari by installing Red Sweater's unsupported [Safari Extension](http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/2681/subscribe-to-feed-1-0b4).

Answer (score -1):

Tbodt I would recommend using Pronto Push app exclusively for OSX Mavericks!

**Get Desktop Notifications From any RSS Feed in Mavericks Using Pronto Push**

> http://www.mactrast.com/2013/10/get-desktop-notifications-rss-feed-mavericks-using-pronto-push/

Comment: Apparantly, Pronto Push is [temporarily unavailable](http://www.prontopush.com).

Comment: Update: Not anymore.

Comment: Per the above re: ProntoPush - they went out of business. Just an FYI. >Well we gave it another try but unfortunately managing Pronto Push has taken up too much time and money. Thanks again to all the beta users!</p>&mdash; Pronto Push (@prontopush)

Comment: And now it looks like you're back, back yet again?  The current page says "© ProntoPush 2014 - Beta 0.1 (Oct 25, 2014)"